# How do you use srgbClr in openpyxl ColorChoices

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I use colors that are not represented by the colornames like RGB.
Sorry, I don't understand the documents but there are no examples. Here is my code:

```
series4Total = chart1.series[3]
fill4Total =  PatternFillProperties(prst="pct5")
fill4Total.foreground = ColorChoice(srgbClr='30,144,255') # dodgerBlue: R:30 G: 144 B: 255
fill4Total.background = ColorChoice(srgbClr='30,144,255')
series4Total.graphicalProperties.pattFill = fill4Total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

srgbClr needs a HEX value
So try this:

```
ColorChoice(srgbClr='1E90FF') # for dodgerBlue: R:30 G: 144 B: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly srgbClr has this definition but I tried to simplify the API a bit where possible.